# UIImageView in UIScrollView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I want to have an `UIImageView` in an `UIScrollView`. But I it doesn't show any picture when I load it. My code looks like this in my `viewController` in the function `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plan.gif"];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
scrollView.contentSize = image.size;
[self updateUI];
```

In my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
TestAppViewController *tavc = [[TestAppViewController alloc] init];
[self.window addSubview:tavc.view];
```

Comment: Have you added : [self.view addSubview: scrollView];    ?or it's missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Check that your image name `@"plan.gif"` is correct. Double-check.
2) Init your `UIImageView` with a frame and add the image later.

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
   CGRectMake(0,0,scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)]; 
// or choose another size
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plan.gif"];
```

Comment: I just tried it, doesn't work. I think it's cause my scrollView doesn't show up.

Am I doing it wrong somehow with my scrollView maybe? Maybe I shouldn't do it in my ViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added the image to the project. Also, make sure that the file name is exactly the same (cAsE sensitive & correct extension).

Comment: Have added the image to the protect, and it's exactly the same :S